# Twitter API, 404 error after retweet action

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I can successfuly post statuses but I'm stuck with retweet.

I'm trying to retweet a tweet by using Twitter API and tmhOauth with following snippet:

```
$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array( 'consumer_key'    => YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY,
            'consumer_secret' => YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET,
            'user_token'      => $atoken1,
            'user_secret'     => $atoken2, ));
$code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1/statuses/retweet'),
        array('id' => '223136515088318466' ));
```

But this code gives following error:

```
[errors] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [message] => Sorry, that page does not exist
                [code] => 34
            )

    )
```

But I can see that status exists:
https://twitter.com/Sekban_iCemil/status/223136515088318466

I'm pretty sure that consumer key and secret is correct, and user token and secret is authorized by user.

What do I miss ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your URL is not `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweet` but `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweet/223136515088318466.json`. It's written in the documentation : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/retweet/%3Aid

Comment: the problem was about my api implementation. tmhoauth doesn't support array based URL for retweets. I solved it by passing long URL while POSTing.

Comment: can you show us what was the exact code I faced the same issue